# what is the value of \thecontentslabel for a chapter*

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, books

I am customizing my toc, but cannot figure out what the value of `\thecontentslabel` is for chapters that are marked not to be numbered...

In general where are these commands described? I don't know where the manual is. Tried KOMA-Script but didn't find anything.

Comment: `\chapter*` writes no entry in the `.toc` file.

Comment: You can insert unnumbered chapters in the table of contents (automatically) with the help of the `titlesec/titletoc` package.

Comment: Using a KOMA-Script class there are `\addchap` and `\addsec` commands to get an unnumbered chapter or section which are automatically inserted in the table of contents. In addition there are some options that affect the layout of the toc. There are documentations in [English](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) and [German](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide.pdf) and also a [German book](http://www.dante.de/index/Literatur/KOMA-Script.html).